# iOS MDM: Code:20 (Unable to get local issuer certificate)

Tags: ios, ssl, openssl, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I have MDM server. When I enroll the iOS device the push token and other details are sent to the computer. After which, I couldn't able to send command to devices.

From [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-SUBSECTION14) i tried troubleshooting the service. When I try the command

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert YourSSLCertAndPrivateKey.pem -debug -showcerts -CAfile server-ca-cert.pem
```

I get a error saying verify return Code:20 (Unable to get local issuer certificate).

In YourSSLCertAndPrivateKey.pem I kept the MDM PushCert obtained from [this](https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/) site and its plain key, apple root certificate and AppleWWDRCA certificate.

In server-ca-cert.pem I kept the entrust certificate.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to use MDM certificate to go with push Notification. It is wrong.

MDM uses completely different type of certificates and the connect should be given with **gateway.push.apple.com:5223**.